# Huawei 4G Hostspot (e5573s-606) not working in Slitaz(Linux based OS)

Tags: drivers, configuration, wifi-hotspot, huawei, slitaz

I was trying to connect my Huawei 4G Hostspot (e5573s-606) in Slitaz to connect via USB to the internet but it does not connect to the internet, rather, it mounts it as Removable Storage drive. On the same computer I have multiboot Windows 7, whenever I connect the  Huawei 4G Hostspot via USB over there it connects to the Internet and also shows it as removable drive.

I must tell that the first time I connected it to Windows 7, it autoinstalled some drivers and afterwards Internet then started to work.

Do I need some drivers or some other configuration?

Comment: google `usb-modeswitch` and the model of your equipment.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the Huawei driver from [here](http://download.myusbmodem.com/download.php?file=/Huawei%20miscellaneous/HUAWEI%20Data%20Cards%20Linux%20Driver.zip&start=1):

```
wget http://download.myusbmodem.com/home/Huawei%20miscellaneous/HUAWEI%20Data%20Cards%20Linux%20Driver.zip
```

uncompress the `HUAWEI Data Cards Linux Driver.zip` file , you will get `Linux Driver 4.19.19.00.tar.gz` file , extract it then `cd` to `driver` directory and install the driver:

```
cd driver
chmod +x install
./install
```